# Grid area do not adapt to the container height

Tags: html, css, grid

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;

    .container {
        background: red;
        width: 80%;
        height: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    //Grid
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "report  work  play  study"
    "report  exercise  social  selfcare";

    report{
    grid-area:report;
    }

    work-container{
    grid-area:work;
    }   

    play-container{
    grid-area:play;
    }
    
    study-container{
    grid-area:study;
    }

    exercise-container{
    grid-area:exercise;
    }

    social-container{
    grid-area:social;
    }

    selfcare-container{
    grid-area:selfcare;
    }




}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesDesk.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7461cf9184.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Time tracking dashboard</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .attribution a {
      color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Report info container -->
    <div class="report">


      <div class="info">
        <img src="images/image-jeremy.png" alt="">

        <div class="person-info">
          <h2 class="title">
            Report for
          </h2>
          <h3 class="name">
            Jeremy Robson
          </h3>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>Daily</p>
        <p>Weekly</p>
        <p>Monthly</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Work category container -->
    <div class="work-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-work.svg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="work">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Work
        </h2>


        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            5hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            32hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 36hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            103hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 128hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Play -->
    <div class="play-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-play.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="play">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Play
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 8hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 29hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Study -->
    <div class="study-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-study.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="study">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Study
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            13hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 19hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Exercise -->
    <div class="exercise-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-exercise.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="exercise">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Exercise
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 18hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Social -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-social.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Social
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 3hrs
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            21hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Self-care  -->
    <div class="self-care-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-self-care.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="self-care">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Self Care
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            7hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>

    </div>






  </div>


  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500&display=swap");
:root {
  /*## Colors*/
  /*### Primary*/
  --Blue: hsl(246, 80%, 60%);
  --Light-red-1: hsl(15, 100%, 70%);
  /*(work)*/
  --Soft-blue: hsl(195, 74%, 62%);
  /*(play)*/
  --Light-red: hsl(348, 100%, 68%);
  /*(study)*/
  --Lime-green: hsl(145, 58%, 55%);
  /*(exercise)*/
  --Violet: hsl(264, 64%, 52%);
  /*(social)*/
  --Soft-orange: hsl(43, 84%, 65%);
  /*(self care)*/
  /*### Neutral*/
  --Very-dark-blue: hsl(226, 43%, 10%);
  --Dark-blue: hsl(235, 46%, 20%);
  --Desaturated-blue: hsl(235, 45%, 61%);
  --Pale-Blue: hsl(236, 100%, 87%);
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
}
body .container {
  background: red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "report  work  play  study" "report  exercise  social  selfcare";
}
body .container .report {
  grid-area: report;
  background-color: violet;
  height: 56.5%;
}

body .container .work-container {
  grid-area: work;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: violet;
}

body .container .study-container {
  grid-area: study;
}
body .container .exercise-container {
  grid-area: exercise;
}
body .container .social-container {
  grid-area: social;
}
body .container .selfcare-container {
  grid-area: selfcare;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesDesk.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7461cf9184.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Time tracking dashboard</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .attribution a {
      color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Report info container -->
    <div class="report">


      <div class="info">
        <img src="images/image-jeremy.png" alt="">

        <div class="person-info">
          <h2 class="title">
            Report for
          </h2>
          <h3 class="name">
            Jeremy Robson
          </h3>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>Daily</p>
        <p>Weekly</p>
        <p>Monthly</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Work category container -->
    <div class="work-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-work.svg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="work">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Work
        </h2>


        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            5hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            32hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 36hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            103hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 128hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Play -->
    <div class="play-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-play.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="play">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Play
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 8hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 29hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Study -->
    <div class="study-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-study.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="study">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Study
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            13hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 19hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Exercise -->
    <div class="exercise-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-exercise.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="exercise">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Exercise
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 18hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Social -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-social.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Social
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 3hrs
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            21hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Self-care  -->
    <div class="self-care-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-self-care.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="self-care">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Self Care
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            7hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>

    </div>






  </div>


  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

so I am trying to make a grid with 2 rows and 4 columns, but when I do each column of the first row covers even more of the height of my 'grid container'
and the second one is created below as the container was the double of height. So I wonder what is wrong with my code. If you could help me I will very much appreciate. Thank you.

Here I have the .scss file:

```
        body {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;

    .container {
        background: red;
        width: 80%;
        height: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    //Grid
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "report  work  play  study"
    "report  exercise  social  selfcare";

    report{
    grid-area:report;
    }

    work-container{
    grid-area:work;
    }   

    play-container{
    grid-area:play;
    }
    
    study-container{
    grid-area:study;
    }

    exercise-container{
    grid-area:exercise;
    }

    social-container{
    grid-area:social;
    }

    selfcare-container{
    grid-area:selfcare;
    }
}
```

[image: Here below I attatch a screenshot of what it looks like]

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet - including the HTML. The image looks right in the sense the content of each item is visible. Did you want it to scroll instead?

Comment: Yeah, sure. No what i want is that the two rows are inside the container, so that they have half their height. I want all the content just inside that container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following answers will help you

- I have worked only on your CSS code, I didn't change your html
  structure.
- Better to you ideal height for .container element.

**Target content overflow for each grid (each .container > div elements)**

Added following additional CSS code in to your style

```
body .container > div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Please check the following code snippet

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500&display=swap");
:root {
  /*## Colors*/
  /*### Primary*/
  --Blue: hsl(246, 80%, 60%);
  --Light-red-1: hsl(15, 100%, 70%);
  /*(work)*/
  --Soft-blue: hsl(195, 74%, 62%);
  /*(play)*/
  --Light-red: hsl(348, 100%, 68%);
  /*(study)*/
  --Lime-green: hsl(145, 58%, 55%);
  /*(exercise)*/
  --Violet: hsl(264, 64%, 52%);
  /*(social)*/
  --Soft-orange: hsl(43, 84%, 65%);
  /*(self care)*/
  /*### Neutral*/
  --Very-dark-blue: hsl(226, 43%, 10%);
  --Dark-blue: hsl(235, 46%, 20%);
  --Desaturated-blue: hsl(235, 45%, 61%);
  --Pale-Blue: hsl(236, 100%, 87%);
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
}
body .container {
  background: red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "report  work  play  study" "report  exercise  social  selfcare";
}

body .container > div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body .container .report {
  grid-area: report;
  background-color: violet;
  height: 56.5%;
}

body .container .work-container {
  grid-area: work;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: violet;
}

body .container .study-container {
  grid-area: study;
}
body .container .exercise-container {
  grid-area: exercise;
}
body .container .social-container {
  grid-area: social;
}
body .container .selfcare-container {
  grid-area: selfcare;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesDesk.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7461cf9184.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Time tracking dashboard</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .attribution a {
      color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Report info container -->
    <div class="report">


      <div class="info">
        <img src="images/image-jeremy.png" alt="">

        <div class="person-info">
          <h2 class="title">
            Report for
          </h2>
          <h3 class="name">
            Jeremy Robson
          </h3>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>Daily</p>
        <p>Weekly</p>
        <p>Monthly</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Work category container -->
    <div class="work-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-work.svg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="work">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Work
        </h2>


        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            5hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            32hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 36hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            103hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 128hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Play -->
    <div class="play-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-play.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="play">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Play
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 8hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 29hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Study -->
    <div class="study-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-study.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="study">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Study
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            13hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 19hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Exercise -->
    <div class="exercise-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-exercise.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="exercise">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Exercise
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 18hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Social -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-social.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Social
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 3hrs
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            21hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Self-care  -->
    <div class="self-care-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-self-care.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="self-care">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Self Care
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            7hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>

    </div>






  </div>


  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Target content overflow for grid-container (.container element)**

Added following additional CSS code in to your style

```
body .container {
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Please check the following code snippet

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500&display=swap");
:root {
  /*## Colors*/
  /*### Primary*/
  --Blue: hsl(246, 80%, 60%);
  --Light-red-1: hsl(15, 100%, 70%);
  /*(work)*/
  --Soft-blue: hsl(195, 74%, 62%);
  /*(play)*/
  --Light-red: hsl(348, 100%, 68%);
  /*(study)*/
  --Lime-green: hsl(145, 58%, 55%);
  /*(exercise)*/
  --Violet: hsl(264, 64%, 52%);
  /*(social)*/
  --Soft-orange: hsl(43, 84%, 65%);
  /*(self care)*/
  /*### Neutral*/
  --Very-dark-blue: hsl(226, 43%, 10%);
  --Dark-blue: hsl(235, 46%, 20%);
  --Desaturated-blue: hsl(235, 45%, 61%);
  --Pale-Blue: hsl(236, 100%, 87%);
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
}
body .container {
  background: red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "report  work  play  study" "report  exercise  social  selfcare";
  overflow-y: auto;
}


body .container .report {
  grid-area: report;
  background-color: violet;
  height: 56.5%;
}

body .container .work-container {
  grid-area: work;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: violet;
}

body .container .study-container {
  grid-area: study;
}
body .container .exercise-container {
  grid-area: exercise;
}
body .container .social-container {
  grid-area: social;
}
body .container .selfcare-container {
  grid-area: selfcare;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesDesk.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7461cf9184.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Time tracking dashboard</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .attribution a {
      color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Report info container -->
    <div class="report">


      <div class="info">
        <img src="images/image-jeremy.png" alt="">

        <div class="person-info">
          <h2 class="title">
            Report for
          </h2>
          <h3 class="name">
            Jeremy Robson
          </h3>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>Daily</p>
        <p>Weekly</p>
        <p>Monthly</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Work category container -->
    <div class="work-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-work.svg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="work">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Work
        </h2>


        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            5hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            32hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 36hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            103hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 128hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Play -->
    <div class="play-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-play.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="play">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Play
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 8hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 29hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Study -->
    <div class="study-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-study.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="study">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Study
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            13hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 19hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Exercise -->
    <div class="exercise-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-exercise.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="exercise">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Exercise
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 18hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Social -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-social.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Social
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 3hrs
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            21hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Self-care  -->
    <div class="self-care-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-self-care.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="self-care">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Self Care
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            7hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>

    </div>






  </div>


  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the content is very much longer than the available height (at least on the max viewport I was able to have) then you will have to make it scroll if it is to be contained within the container element. ie:

`.container > div { overflow: scroll; }`

otherwise the content will push the areas down to make sure the content fits in.

The container really doesn't have much height so there will be a lot of scrolling which doesn't look great, and will it be difficult for the user to understand that they have to scroll through each one to see what it says?

Personally I would recomment scrapping the very constrained container size and letting the content decide the height of the grid areas so the user has at most one scrolling bar to cope with - but of course I don't know exactly your use case or who the users will be.

Here's the snippet with the scrolling included so your requirement to fit everything into the container as specified is met:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500&display=swap");
:root {
  /*## Colors*/
  /*### Primary*/
  --Blue: hsl(246, 80%, 60%);
  --Light-red-1: hsl(15, 100%, 70%);
  /*(work)*/
  --Soft-blue: hsl(195, 74%, 62%);
  /*(play)*/
  --Light-red: hsl(348, 100%, 68%);
  /*(study)*/
  --Lime-green: hsl(145, 58%, 55%);
  /*(exercise)*/
  --Violet: hsl(264, 64%, 52%);
  /*(social)*/
  --Soft-orange: hsl(43, 84%, 65%);
  /*(self care)*/
  /*### Neutral*/
  --Very-dark-blue: hsl(226, 43%, 10%);
  --Dark-blue: hsl(235, 46%, 20%);
  --Desaturated-blue: hsl(235, 45%, 61%);
  --Pale-Blue: hsl(236, 100%, 87%);
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
}

body .container {
  background: red;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "report  work  play  study" "report  exercise  social  selfcare";
}


/* ADDED */

body .container>div {
  overflow: scroll;
}

body .container .report {
  grid-area: report;
  background-color: violet;
  height: 56.5%;
}

body .container .work-container {
  grid-area: work;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: violet;
}

body .container .study-container {
  grid-area: study;
}

body .container .exercise-container {
  grid-area: exercise;
}

body .container .social-container {
  grid-area: social;
}

body .container .selfcare-container {
  grid-area: selfcare;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesDesk.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7461cf9184.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Time tracking dashboard</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .attribution a {
      color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Report info container -->
    <div class="report">


      <div class="info">
        <img src="images/image-jeremy.png" alt="">

        <div class="person-info">
          <h2 class="title">
            Report for
          </h2>
          <h3 class="name">
            Jeremy Robson
          </h3>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p>Daily</p>
        <p>Weekly</p>
        <p>Monthly</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Work category container -->
    <div class="work-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-work.svg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="work">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Work
        </h2>


        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            5hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            32hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 36hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            103hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 128hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Play -->
    <div class="play-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-play.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="play">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Play
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 8hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 29hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Study -->
    <div class="study-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-study.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="study">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Study
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 7hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            13hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 19hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Exercise -->
    <div class="exercise-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-exercise.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="exercise">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Exercise
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            4hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 18hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Social -->
    <div class="social-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-social.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Social
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            1hr
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 3hrs
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            5hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 10hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            21hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 23hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Self-care  -->
    <div class="self-care-container">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="images/icon-self-care.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="self-care">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
        <h2 class="category">
          Self Care
        </h2>

        <!-- Daily section -->
        <section class="category-daily">
          <h3 class="hours-daily">
            0hrs
            <!-- daily -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-daily-previous">
            Previous - 1hr
            <!-- daily -->></p>
        </section>

        <!--  Weekly section -->
        <section class="category-weekly">
          <h3 class="hours-weekly">
            2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-weekly-previous">
            Previous - 2hrs
            <!-- weekly -->
          </p>
        </section>

        <!-- Monthly section -->
        <section class="category-monthly">
          <h3 class="hours-monthly">
            7hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </h3>
          <p class="hours-monthly-previous">
            Previous - 11hrs
            <!-- monthly -->
          </p>
        </section>


      </div>

    </div>






  </div>


  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```